# How to make async pause in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, loops

I have a program written in C# (Visual Studio), that works on a tray.
I want it to do one action every 10 minutes.
I have following code now:

```
while(true)
{
Thread.Sleep(10000);
// my stuff
}
```

But it doesn't work. It freezes a program.

Comment: By the way, you `Sleep` for 10 seconds, not minutes. The `Sleep` method takes the number of _milliseconds_ as a parameter. So if you want to sleep for 10 minutes you should write `Sleep(600000)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the timer object and not create a while loop.

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer = new  System.Timers.Timer();
_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
//30 seconds
_timer.Interval = 30000;
_timer.Start();

private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //do your logic
}
```

Comment: Prefer to use the System.Threading.Timer class rather than the System.Timers.Timer class.  Just a tid-bit from Jeffrey Richter...

Comment: What is the difference between them?

Comment: The below link shows the difference between them
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/656f8b0f-77f7-42a7-a34c-0325ffef6c0a

Comment: System.Timer.Timer is a wrapper around System.Threading.Timer.  Furthermore, it derives from ComponentModel's Component class, which means it can be used on a design surface in Visual Studio (a rare usage, in my experience).  Its extra capabilities only exist for the Visual Studio design surface.  If you are not using a design surface, it simply has a cluttered interface for you to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Thread.Sleep makes the calling thead Sleep for an X ammount of time. If this thread is the frontend thread (the one responsible for handling messages), it will indeed freeze the application since any message for handling events or repainting wont be handeled untill the Thread wakes up again and gets a chance of handling the messages.

What you should do is schedule this logic every 10 seconds.

Drop a timer on your form and specify it to run each 10 seconds. Within the Tick event, call your custom action.

Answer (score 1):

Thread.Sleep "stops" the current thread. if you only have one thread, everything is paused.

What do you want to achieve ?

Perhaps you need a second thread, or perhaps the better solution a timer which triggers a action every 10 minutes

s. [Task.StartNew()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx) or [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kbf0f1ct%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)